# Determining CMHC insurance premium

Tags: canada, mortgage, real-estate, hst

Is the calculation based on purchase price with HST or without HST?

For example, the property is being purchased from the builder and the stated purchase price includes HST.  If the posted price is $1,000,100, including HST, does this fall under the criteria of requiring a 20% downpayment? Or not since the base price of the property is really $885K (1,000,100 * 87%)?

Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised that CMHC seems to have no reference to this.  I can only guess that it's based on the $1,000,100 since they will insure based on a `as-improved property value` of $1,000,000.

> For CMHC-insured mortgage loans, the maximum purchase price or
>   as-improved property value must be below $1,000,000, when the
>   loan-to-value ratio is greater than 80%.

I would assume this means they don't want insure homes with a market value greater than $1,000,000.  HST becomes part of the market value after you've paid it since the next buyer won't have to.  They should be willing to pay 15% more for a house with the tax already paid up.